# How to change the position of Navigation Section in Magento 2.3.3 through CSS?

Tags: html, css, magento, e-commerce, magento2

I am trying to reposition the entire block of navigation section in a different position than it is right now, e.g. moving it a little upward as it is shown in the attachment.

I have tried to modify the CSS file under `..porto/web/css/header/type2.css` with the class `.nav-sections`. I have tested with other possible `CSS` classes and after so many attempts I haven't found it working; now I am looking for help. Can anyone please give me any hint on this issue? I am using porto theme with my site.

[image: attachment]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you would want to edit the .xml file from the correct module within your own frontend theme. But if your specifically looking to just edit the css the below might work:

```
.page-header.type2.header-newskin .nav-sections {
text-align: center;
position: absolute;
top: 70px;
left: 35%;
}
```

you can just tweak the top and left positions to your needs.